# RegEx- allow alpha,numeric with only special char Comma - but no precceeding or succeeding commas

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i need help in forming an regular expression that allow Alpha,Numeric and only special character comma - but comma should not be present at starting or ending or no middle blank commas..
Right now i am using the below regex which works fine for the aplha-numeric-comma , but it will allow comma at beginning or ending or blank commas.

/^[a-zA-Z0-9,]*$/  --> working regex that allows alpha-numeric-comma

so need help in regex for the above requirement of no precceeding/succeeding/blank commas in the middle...

correct case : abc,abc12,asdf,qwer23
wrong case : ,abc,abc12,asdf,qwer23
wrong case: abc,abc12,asdf,qwer23,
wrong case : abc,abc12,,asdf,qwer23

struck for the last 2 hrs in fixing this and any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: what do you mean by "blank commas"?

Comment: Is it for Java or JS?

Comment: @ Stribizew it is for JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest splitting out the comma from the char class and use a `*` quantified group wrapping the whole expression with an optional non-capturing group around an obligatory subpattern (that requires at least 1 char) (as your regex also allows an empty string):

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mUbfcb/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)?` - an optional sequence of (=the whole string may be empty):

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric
  - `(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - zero or more (due to `*`) sequences of:

    - `,` - comma
    - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var test = [
    "abc,abc12,asdf,qwer23", // correct 
    ",abc,abc12,asdf,qwer23", // incorrect
    "abc,abc12,asdf,qwer23,", // incorrect
    "abc,abc12,,asdf,qwer23" ]; // incorrect
var rx = /^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)?$/;
for (var s of test) {
  console.log(s + " => " + rx.test(s));
}
```

Comment: thanks Wiktor Stribiżew .. i am using this for Jquery validation and the regex ur provided, working fine..Thank you very much...